# I have made some changes in middleware, Laravel redirects too many times to login

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.6

Here is my middleware code. I want to redirect the user to login page if the role is not equal to 1. What's wrong with the below code?

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Models\Enrollment;

    use Closure;

    class adminAuth
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
         public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
         {
               //if the logined user role is equal to 1, the user should continue
             if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role == 1) {
               return $next($request);
              }
              else
              {
                  //otherwise redirect the user to login
                  return redirect('/login');
              }


         }
    }
```

Comment: what happens when a user is not logged in looks like it will get stuck in loop

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you’re trying to redirect a logged in user with a role other than 1 to the login page, but there’ll be separate middleware that redirects the user away. What’s the point of showing a logged in user a login page? But when this second redirect’s happening, it’s triggering your `adminAuth` middleware again, which is just going to cause an infinite redirect loop.

The problem is, you’re mixing authentication with *authorisation*. Checking if a user is logged in or not is authentication. Checking *what* a logged in user can do is authorisation.

If only users with a role of 1 (I’m guessing some sort of admin role) then you should display a “Forbidden” page to users with any other role:

```php
class VerifyUserIsAdministrator
{
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->role == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403, 'User is not an administrator');
    }
}
```

Also, consider a better way to check roles. The integer `1` for a role means nothing to someone new working with your code. If role 1 *is* an administrator, then maybe create a method on your `User` model and use that instead:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function isAdministrator()
    {
        return $this->role == 1;
    }
}
```

---

```php
class VerifyUserIsAdministrator
{
    public function handle()
    {
        if ($request->user()->isAdministrator()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403, 'User is not an administrator');
    }
}
```

Notice how the logic in your middleware becomes much more readable?